# Change directory of conda for new version of Julia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, kernel, jupyter, conda

I have changed my computer and also updated Julia (from 1.6 to 1.8). Jupyter notebook does not propose the new version of Julia as Kernel and I cannot add it by doing:

```
Pkg.build("Ijulia")
```

I got the following error:

ERROR: Error building `Conda`:
┌ Info: CONDA_EXE not found. Reverting to default in ROOTENV
│   CONDA_EXE = "/Users/pololebo/.julia/conda/3/bin/conda"
└   ROOTENV = "/Users/pololebo/.julia/conda/3"
ERROR: LoadError: IOError: mkdir("/Users/pololebo"; mode=0o777): permission denied (EACCES)

with "pololebo" my previous user identifier. Now it is "Pol". How I can fix it?

Comment: How did you update Julia? And did you copy over the old `.julia` folder to your new user account or something? Any other steps you took during/after the update, like copying over the Project.toml or anything else?

Comment: I only reinstalled Julia 1.8 and deleted the old version. I think I still have the Julia folder (but don't know if it is at the right place). Am I suppose to do something with the Project.toml ?

Comment: `rm -rf /Users/pololebo/.julia/`  and then try installing Julia packages.  `ENV["PYTHON"]=""` is also a good idea before `Pkg.add("PyCall")` BTW. it is `IJulia` not `Ijulia`

Comment: I don't have any .julia folder within my computer. I tried your suggestion, without success unfortunately.

Comment: Do you not have a `/User/Pol/.julia/` folder either? If not, what does `DEPOT_PATH[1]` print in the REPL? Under that path, there should be a `conda/deps.jl` and a `packages/Conda/<some alphanumeric code>/deps/deps.jl`. Delete both of them and try `build Conda` and `build IJulia` again.

Comment: try in REPL: ENV["Python"] = ""; ]build Conda

Comment: I desinstalled Anaconda and Julia, then I installed Miniconda from Julia shell. It works now but I don't know what it is going to happen if I install Anaconda again.

Comment: You can now install Anaconda without a problem until you build Conda again, such as when you change Julia versions. If the problem then occurs, you will need to set ENV{"PYTHON"} = "" and then rebuild Pycall and Conda in a Julia session with ENV["PYTHON"] set to the empty string. If you do not do this, PyCall may set itself to use your Anaconda session, and this will cause a library "version hell" situation since several Julia packages expect libraries to be available in versions Anaconda does not provide.